# Need to read XMI file through java code without using any tool (like argouml)

Tags: xmi

Is there any way i can read an XMI file by writing java code rather that using nay tool(like EMF, MDI etc)? I want to write a java program which can read all the classes and attributes in an xmi file and then load then in the memory.

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

That´s quite easy. You just need to write a Java program that parses the XML File and look for the classes of the UML model (XML elements named "Class"). Attributs appear as nested elements (Classifier.feature and then Attribute)

Comment: Hi Jordi,
thanks for your reply. Actually i want to create a domain model for my project which will parse/read the different excel sheets and then will get the values of classes, relations and their instances. Hence i can not code the classes in the domain model directly as Java classes, and i have to implement a generic framework that can read any domain model (UML class diagram) from a file in a suitable format (XMI?).

Comment: So, i thought about the using xmi format for defining the uml classes format. Could you please tell me that am i going in right direction(by reading the xmi and store the classes,relationships in some variables and collection). Can you give me any other idea how to handle this situation?
Thanks.

Comment: that´s exactly what I was saying. At the Java level you´ll have a UMLClass class, a UMLAttribute class,... and  you will instantiate these classes with the info of the UML model obtained from the XMI file.

Answer (score 0):

You have 3 options.

- Use an implementation of the [JMI](http://java.sun.com/products/jmi/) specification (didn't find any until now)
- use ECore as a lib (or is that one really eclipse-dependant?)
- Parse the XML with some XML-reader/-library and just pull what you need